# How do I fix error CS0111 in Unity/Vscode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm just starting to learn to develop games in Unity with Vscode, so I found a Brackeys tutorial on it. I've been watching the series for a while, until I came across an issue; I got an error while following along with the 9th episode that says:
Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(20,6): error CS0111: Type 'GameManager' already defines a member called 'Restart' with the same parameter types

I have tried to figure out the issue based on what the error says, but I couldn't get it to work. I was hoping someone could help.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   
bool gameHasEnded = false;
public float restartDelay = 1f;
public void CompleteLevel ()
{Debug.Log ("You did it!");
}
public void EndGame ()
{
    if (gameHasEnded == false)
   { 
       gameHasEnded = true;
    Debug.Log ("Game Over");
   Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
    }
}
 

void Restart ()
{
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}


}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right file and that you've saved it? Line 9 of the code in the question does not match that error message.

Comment: Oh Sorry,  I copied the wrong thing. Here is the error:                                    Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(20,6): error CS0111: Type 'GameManager' already defines a member called 'Restart' with the same parameter types

Answer (score 0):

It says that your "Restart'" method has been redefined. Try changing the "Restart" method to the "Restarts" method.

```
 void Restarts ()
{
  SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);    
}
```

thank you hope it helps

Comment: That worked, but now  it's giving me this error: Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(9,13): error CS0111: Type 'GameManager' already defines a member called 'EndGame' with the same parameter types. Which doesn't make sense because line 9 doesn't match up with what the error says.

Comment: Thank you, please try changing the name of the "EndGame" method, for example, to "EndGames"